# Two JFrames side by side

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Is it possible to set up two different JFrames and show them **side by side**? Without use Internalframe, multiple Jpanels etc. .

Comment: Take a look at JFrame - [setLocation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFramesetLocationintxinty.htm) method, which combined with setting size of frames, can position both side by side

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you mean two application windows side by side, or two sections (in one application window) side by side?

Comment: Not everything possible is wise.  Seems like you want one JFrame with two JPanels side by side.

Comment: @makciook Yes, it can be do as you said. But is there another posibility?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I mean 2 jframes

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I think about that, bu i am interested different method now

Comment: I really would consider @GilbertLeBlanc 's advice especially considering the answers provided in [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

1st position your frames on each screen devices.

```
frame1.setLocation(pointOnFirstScreen);
frame2.setLocation(pointOnSecondScreen);
```

working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GuiApp1 {
protected void twoscreen() {
Point p1 = null;
Point p2 = null;
for (GraphicsDevice gd : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ().getScreenDevices()) {
    if (p1 == null) {
        p1 = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getLocation();
    } else if (p2 == null) {
        p2 = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getLocation();
    }
}
if (p2 == null) {
    p2 = p1;
}
createFrameAtLocation(p1);
createFrameAtLocation(p2);
 }

 private void createFrameAtLocation(Point p) {
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("Test frame on two screens");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
final JTextArea textareaA = new JTextArea(24, 80);
textareaA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
panel.add(textareaA, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setLocation(p);
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


    public void run() {
        new GuiApp1().twoscreen();
    }
});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as follows;

```
JFrame leftFrame = new JFrame();

// get the top left point of the left frame
Point leftFrameLocation = leftFrame.getLocation();
// then make a new point with the same top (y) and add the width of the frame (x)
Point rightFrameLocation = new Point(
            leftFrameLocation.x + leftFrame.getWidth(),
            leftFrameLocation.y);

JFrame rightFrame = new JFrame();
rightFrame.setLocation(rightFrameLocation); // and that's the new location
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a very simple example; for my own uses I do the same thing with non-modal JDialogs.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frameL = new JFrame("Left Frame");
        frameL.setSize(400, 200); // this size arbitrary; set how you need.
        frameL.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameL.setVisible(true);

        Point p = frameL.getLocationOnScreen();
        Dimension d = frameL.getSize();

        JFrame frameR = new JFrame("Right Frame");
        frameR.setSize(300, 160); // this size arbitrary; set how you need.
        frameR.setLocation((p.x + d.width), p.y);
        frameR.setVisible(true);

        while(frameL.isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```